# Fatal memory error in Sylius production environment

Tags: symfony, sylius

Trying to access my Sylius site in production environment but I'm running in a memory error:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in *directoryname*/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2798"

I found I can bypass the problem by setting AppKernel('prod', true), but I read that this is bad practice for some reason.

Anyone run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons as 128MB of RAM is not that much to exhaust.

#### 1. Cache is not warmed up

If your cache is not warmed up, and the app needs to generate all the files, it can eat up lot of RAM on the first request.

Most of the time this shouldn't be the case in production mode, if you run `composer install` or use some deploy mechanism (capistrano, deployer) that calls `> php app\console cache:clear` during deployment as this will also prime the cache.

Try running composer install manually on the server as this should generate cache after building autoload files.

#### 2. GD image resize on images with big dimensions (not size)

If you use image resizing with GD it will always uncompress the image. That means that jpeg image of 3000x3000 with size 1KB, where every single pixel is #fff will need around 35-54MB or RAM

`(3000 x 3000 x 4(rgba)) / 1024^2 = 34.3MB`

Add to this some requirements for processing, and it can easily reach over 128MB. Also people tend to upload images with dimensions up to 10k these days.

> solution: switch to imagick / gmagick or enormously increase RAM

#### 3. Your app logic really uses up that much RAM

- Profile your code, see how much memory is used
- See if you don't load/build somewhere thousand of objects
- Just simple increase your RAM to 256 / 512 and see it helps

#### 4. You got hidden infinite loop because of

- old session data - clear sessions
- configuration difference on your prod and dev machine (or config file)

Comment: Thanks! I'll work through these suggestions and see if I can figure out what is happening. I'm getting this error no matter what I try to load as the homepage, so I don't think it is content-specific.